# convert strings like 'abcd="efgh"' to a dicts like {'abcd': 'efgh'}

Tags: python, string, dictionary, type-conversion

I'd like to convert lists of formatted strings into a dictionnary.

the strings formatted like this:

```
str = 'abcd="efgh"'
```

And i'd like to get this into a dict like this:

```
d = {'abcd': 'efgh'}
```

Example:

```
l = ['abc="efg"', 'hij="klm"', 'nop="qrs"']
```

into >

```
d = {'abc': 'efg', 'hij': 'klm', 'nop' :'qrs'}
```

I tried the following :

```
d = dict(element.split('=') for element in l)
```

-> but this doesn't work

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try something? We don't encourage questions that don't demonstrate minimal efforts.

Comment: Sorry about that: I tried the following d = dict(element.split('=') for element in l) but this doesn't work.

Comment: Oh actually this works... I kept getting this error: ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #1 has length 1; 2 is required, I just realized this is because my list had elements with unexpected formatting...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse the list and break each element using the `split` method and then add it to `dict`. Adding sample code:

```
d = {}
for element in l:
    string_elements = element.split("=")
    d[string_elements[0]] = string_elements[1].replace('"','')
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, I've come up with this, what do you think? d = dict(element.replace('"', '').split('=') for element in l)

Comment: Choosing the for loop or comprehension is a matter of personal preference. The one liner is clever, but some people might find it harder to understand. Choose whatever you / other users of your code will find easy to understand when you / they look at the code in future.